# rails namespace routes and controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, namespaces, routes, partials

i just can not figure out the best way to handle the routes / controller with the following namespace.
i´d just like to have the following setup:

```
.../manage/rooms/  ( <%= @ rooms.number_of_rooms%>, <%= @ rooms.title %> )
.../manage/fuu/     ( <%= @ fuu.id %>...) 
..manage/foo/       ...
```

i know this is done by 
routes.rb

```
namespace :manage do
resources :rooms, :fuu, :foo
end
```

and under ...`controller/manage/rooms_controller.rb` and `fuu_controller.rb` and `foo...`
example:

```
class Manage::RoomsController < ApplicationController

 index
 @rooms = Rooms.all
 end
 def create
 @room = Room.new(room_params)
  if @room.save
   redirect_to [:manage, @room]
  else
   render 'new'
 end
 ...
end
```

and a controller under `controller/manage_controller.rb`

```
class ManageController < ApplicationController
end
```

so here is my question i do like to use all of my forms and variables `@rooms.title...`who are under `.../manage/rooms/ .../manage/fuu/ ....` 
under the `.../manage/index.html.erb`

is the best way to do it via the controller e.g. render partial or changing the controller which the routes point to?

thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use partials in this situation. If they are all shared in that namespace, it makes sense for the location to be the manage views directory. If they weren't namespaced but still being shared, I'd create a 'shared' directory in views.

Comment: thank you! can you tell me how the partials should look like? i tried <% render :partial => '/manage/rooms/index' %> but that did not work...